# Freebsd kernel crash: run ddb commands before panic

Tags: kernel, freebsd, kgdb

I have a FreeBSD system running into crashes. I think it will be useful to run some ddb commands and collect data before writing the core file. I wanted to do this automatically for all the crashes. Has someone done this before ?

Answer (score 0):

For doing stuff automatically i suggest to debug with GDB, as it is written in the handbook https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/kerneldebug.html

See the GDB documentation about scripting GDB
https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-Files.html

If you must use DDB, it is possible to direct DDB to a serial console and use a program on another machine to communicate with it.